# inverting bitmap colors using C doesn't change the image

Tags: c, bitmap, bmp

I'm writing a program to invert the colors of a bitmap image. I used the ~ operator on unsigned char RGB values to invert the colors, and print statements are showing that the numbers are correctly inverted. However I think maybe something is going wrong with my fwrite, because the image is not changing.

```
void invert_colors(struct head h, FILE* filep, struct dib_h dibh){

    fseek(file_p, (int)*h.offset_to_pixels, SEEK_SET);
    int wid;
    int len;

    struct pixel pix;

    for (len = 0; len < (int)*dibh.imgheight; len++){
        for (wid = 0; wid < (int)*dibh.imgwidth; wid++){


            fread(&pix, 3, 1, filep);  
            pix.red = ~(pix.red);

            pix.green = ~(pix.green);
            pix.blue = ~(pix.blue);

            fseek(filep, -3, SEEK_CUR); 


            fwrite(pix, 3, 1, filep);
        }
      fseek(filep, (((int)*dibh.imgwidth)*3)%4, SEEK_CUR);

    }
    fclose(filep);
```

Comment: What's in the file when you're done?

Comment: This is not a [mcve] - you do not show how you opened the file. That may be the problem.

Comment: @nicomp the file is unchanged

Comment: why do you actually searching backwards? i'm little drunk now so i'm not sure but you set your pointer to offset where pixel data starts and you searching backwards, you want to change palette or pixels?

Comment: @Anatoly I read one pixel which advances the pointer, I alter the pixel, then I move the pointer back to where that pixel started to write the altered one in the same spot.

Comment: What is the indirection for in `fseek(file_p, (int)*h.offset_to_pixels, SEEK_SET);`? Did you cast it to silence a compiler warning? Also in `(int)*dibh.height` etc. The arguments `h` and `dibh` are not pointers.

Comment: so you overwriting the same spot again and again?

Comment: @Anatoly `fread` advances the file pointer, `fseek` moves it back, so the data can be overwritten, it moves it 3 bottles forwards, 3 bottles back, and another 3 bottles forward at the `fwrite`.

Comment: oh thanks now i see i thought that fwrite don't change pointer

Comment: @RadLexus you're right, I fixed it

Comment: shouldn't you "wb"?

Comment: The heigth and width are not really `char` arrays (unless you want to build their values bytewise) they are 32-bit unsigned integer values. You are in danger of endian issues here, so I recommend a function to build the value from the (actually *unsigned*) char array. But here you are trying to make it read the `unsigned int` directly, but you missed out the `&` address-of operator.

Comment: `(int)*dibh.header_size` should be `*(int*)(&dibh.header_size)` and the others too - but endianness may be an issue. And as remarked, you did not open the file for writing anyway, nor did you check the success of any file operations.

Comment: @WeatherVane can you explain why it should be `*(int*)(&dibh.header_size)`

Comment: I made a slip there, thinking the 4 char bytes were individual variables, not an array, so I should have put `*(int*)(&dibh.header_size[0])`. The cast `(int*)` is to convert the `char` address to a pointer to `int` and then the first `*` is to deference that `int` pointer. But you should not be doing it this way, you should build the `int` from the 4 bytes values, which must be `unsigned char`.

Comment: Also please be aware that each row of the image stored is always a multiple of 4 bytes, so in some cases there is some alignment to be done. For example, 3 pixels width of 24-bit colour requires 9 bytes, but the row length in the file will be 12 bytes.

Comment: @WeatherVane I accounted for that at the end of each row. Thank you for your help; I am now getting accurate width and height. The image still isn't changing

Comment: You did not open the file for updating, you did not check the file operations were successful. Mode should be `"r+"`

Comment: Except in MSVC mode should be `"r+b"`.

Comment: @Anatoly no, `"wb"` will destroy the file.

Comment: @WeatherVane you're right. It works now, thank you. Except there's a  diagonal line of weird pixels.. I'll try to figure that out

Comment: My guess is your line-end adjustment is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The "rb" option open the file in read mode and not writing. If you want to read and write, you have to use a file positioning function between each input and output. See the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen).